# tectonic faults catalog for plot

Tags: plate-tectonics, tectonics

I looking for a catalog (ideally in a ASCII file) of the major tectonic faults on earth, in order to plot some of them on a map

Any suggestion ?

Comment: For further studies, you can have a look at [Gplates](https://www.gplates.org/). You can produce some really nice plots based on regarded plate reconstructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good database of tectonic plates is available at the [Institute for Geophysics of the University of Texas](http://ig.utexas.edu/marine-and-tectonics/plates-project/). The database includes [present conditions](http://www-udc.ig.utexas.edu/external/plates/0.htm) and [past and future conditions](http://www-udc.ig.utexas.edu/external/plates/recons.htm). They provide ASCII files in their [ftp site](ftp://ftp.ig.utexas.edu).
[image: plates from UTIG] [Source](http://www-udc.ig.utexas.edu/external/plates/0.htm)

Another option is the data from Peter Bird at UCLA that he described in his article ["An updated digital model of plate boundaries", $G^3$, 2003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2001GC000252). He provides the data in ASCII format in their [ftp site](http://peterbird.name/oldFTP/PB2002/) (they include a [readme](http://peterbird.name/oldFTP/PB2002/2001GC000252_readme.txt) file with the description of the data).